# bootstrap grid system is fluid but not static

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I changed my grid system to bootstrap and I'm finding out that its not static. It seems to adjust to the screen size when the `span`'s are specific sizes. I did not want to remove responsive.css file to see if it works. I've seen several sites built using this system and some are static. My question is how do I do this?

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="span3">Logo Placement</div>
    <div class="span4 offset4">Weather Modal</div>
    <div class="span12">Nav placement 940px</div>
    <div class="span12">imageslider placement</div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">
            <div class="span4">sidebar placement</div>
            <div class="span6">body content placement</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It doesn't center, and it seems to shrink based on the browser. I do not know what values to use or what to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just uncheck the "responsive layouts" before you generate and download your code on the bootstrap website. That should make it so your website has a static grid.

Comment: OH wow! thank you...I didn't realize I overlooked this. I was completely oblivious